# Find the number of solutions of a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

$$\log_3(|x-1|)\cdot\log_4(|x-1|)\cdot\log_5(|x-1|) = \log_5(|x-1|) + \log_3(|x-1|)\cdot\log_4(|x-1|)$$
on solving this equation I get this:
$$|x-1|/5 = 4\log_{|x-1|}3$$
What should I do next??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\log_3(|x-1|)$ then $\log_4(|x-1|)=\frac{t}{\log_3(4)}$, $\log_5(|x-1|)=\frac{t}{\log_3(5)}$, and the equation becomes
$$\frac{t^3}{\log_3(4)\cdot \log_3(5)}=\frac{t}{\log_3(5)}+\frac{t^2}{\log_3(4)}.$$
which implies that $t=0$ (and therefore $x=2$ or $x=0$) or $t$ is a solution of this quadratic equation
$$t^2-\log_3(5)t-\log_3(4)=0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: you're right! x=0 and x=2 are roots of the equations. I will get 4 solutions by solving the quadratic equation and hence total of 6 roots.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The equation that you have arrived at is wrong; it does not have the same solutions.

Because $\log_ab=\frac{\log b}{\log a}$ the equation can be written as
$$\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 3}\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 4}\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 5}=\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 5}+\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 3}\frac{\log|x-1|}{\log 4},$$
and setting $y:=\log|x-1|$ this simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{\log3\log4\log5}y^3-\frac{1}{\log3\log4}y^2-\frac{1}{\log5}y=0.$$
One obvious solution is $y=0$, corresponding to $x=0$ and $x=2$. If $y\neq0$ then we can divide by $y$ to get
$$\frac{1}{\log3\log4\log5}y^2-\frac{1}{\log3\log4}y-\frac{1}{\log5}=0,$$
which is a quadratic equation in $y$, which I'm sure you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(3)}\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(4)}\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(5)}=\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(5)}+\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(3)}\frac{\ln|x-1|}{\ln(4)}$$